# delete ch from recursively managed linked list class

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

I built this while loop to delete a ch that matches a given var from a linked list.  I iterate through the list and then delete.  I'd like to manage it through recursion and not iteration.  I'm lost on the syntax.  Never done recursion before.

In the Header...

```
class LinkedList...

bool del(char ch);

struct node
{
    char data;
    node * next;
    node * prev;
};
node * head, *tail;
```

In the source using iterative

```
bool LinkedList::del(char var){

struct node *curr;
struct node *prev;
struct node *next;

//empty?
if (head == NULL){
    cout << "sent an empty..." << endl;
    return false;
}

if (head->data == var){
    next = head->next;
    delete head;
    head = next;
    return true;
}
curr = head->next;

while (curr != NULL){
    if (curr->data == var)
    {
        prev = curr->prev;
        next = curr->next;
        delete curr;
        prev->next = next;
        return true;
    }

    curr = curr->next;

}
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Just 3 cases to check:

- if current node is null - *meaning list is either empty or var doesn't exist in list*
- if current node data is not var
- if current node data is var

#### Sample Code

```
bool LinkedList::del(struct node* curr, char var) {
   if (curr == NULL) {
      // base case: haven't found var in list
      return false;
   }

   if (curr->data != var) {
      // case 2: data != var
      // search next node
      return del(curr->next, var);
   }

   // case 3: data == var
   // found it - delete this node
   struct node* next = curr->next;
   struct node* prev = curr->prev;

   prev->next = next; // time to say goodbye to curr
   delete curr;       // 

   return true;
}

del(head, var); // pass head to start
```

Comment: What does your declaration look like.  I tried .... bool del(struct node* curr, char var); .... My VS is complaining.  Wow nevermind.  Should probably put the declaration after the struct.  Trying it now.

Comment: thanks again for the help.  Works until I try to delete the last ch in the list.  "a, b, c" can delete 'a' or 'b' but if the list is "b, c" and I try to delete 'c' the program hangs.  I'm running through breakpoints now and trying to interpret.

Comment: deleting 1st or last element seems to crash program.

Comment: I'm sure you're frustrated.  Thanks for the help... Here's how I add the characters...  `void LinkedList::add(char ch){

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = new(struct node);
        head->data = ch;
        head->prev = NULL;
        head->next = NULL;
        tail = head;

    }
    else{
        struct node *temp;
        temp = new(struct node);

        temp->data = ch;
        temp->next = NULL;
        tail->next = temp;
        temp->prev = tail;

        tail = temp;
    }

    cout << "Character was added " << ch << endl;
}`

Comment: it's my best interest that you could figure it out yourself. to verify that the list is really "connected", just try printing it from head to tail

Comment: List prints successfully before 1st delete and after 1st delete.  Never gets to print after an attempt to delete 1st or last element.

Comment: hint: if either you delete first or last element, `curr->next` or `curr->prev` will be `null`. check where it crashed using a debugger.